# Detect When Key Lifted - New Unity Input System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I am currently working on a platform video game with Unity and am not sure how to detect when a key is lifted using the new input system.

I would like to know, if possible, can you detect when the key is lifted and assign the value to a bool, using my current settings.

So far, I have this code:

```
    public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.performed)
        {
            jump = true;
            wasJumpLifted = true;
        }

        if (context.canceled)
        {
            wasJumpLifted = false;
        }
        else
        {
            wasJumpLifted = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it will only set wasJumpLifted to true if you press down the jump key again, as the entire function will not be invoked without me pressing the jump key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution

```
public bool isPressed;

public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    // To keep the state in a boolean.
    isPressed = (!context.started || context.performed) ^ context.canceled;
    
    // When the key is pressed down.
    if (context.started && !context.performed)
        Debug.Log("Pressed Down");
    
    // When the key is lifted up.
    if (context.canceled && !context.performed)
        Debug.Log("Lifted Up");
}
```

In my projects I use the one-liner:

```
public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context) => isPressed = (!context.started || context.performed) ^ context.canceled;
```

This can be hard to read, but when do you need to read the code to handle these actions?

Comment: I cannot get it to expect a method with InputAction.CallbackContext. It always expects a method with no params.